# Is it possible to use createChooser but not actually starting the intent (yet)?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

In my app I have a share button which allows the user to share some text through other apps such as Messenger. I use createChooser to let the user select the app they want to use. The tricky part is, after they've selected the app, I don't want to start the selected app immediately, but I need to do some communication with the server first (to get the exact text to share), and I also want to prompt some message on the screen at this stage, and then I can start the share intent of the selected app.
In other words, the chooser is simply an interface for selection, I don't want it to actually start the intent; I will start it manually a little later.

I tried to modify the intents that are collected into the chooser in such a way that they simply redirect back to my own app. However, I have problem retaining their icons and label. No matter what I do, some of the selections always change their icons and labels to those of my own app.

Here's roughly what my current code looks like:

```java
PackageManager pm = activity.getPackageManager();
Intent sendIntent = new Intent()
    .setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text)
    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    .setType("text/plain");

List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
List<LabeledIntent> intentList = new ArrayList<>();
for (ResolveInfo ri : resInfo) {
    String packageName = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
    String name = ri.activityInfo.name;
    if (name.contains("facebook.messenger")
        || name.contains("naver.line")
        || name.contains("android.mms")
        || name.contains("clipboard")
        ) {

        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(packageName, name);
        Intent intent = new Intent(sendIntent)
            .setPackage(packageName)
            .setComponent(cn); // I tried to do somthing here but it doesn't work

        intentList.add(new LabeledIntent(intent, packageName, ri.loadLabel(pm), ri.icon));
        // loadLabel and icon doesn't always get the correct thing
    }
}

Intent first = intentList.remove(0);
Intent[] extra = intentList.toArray(new Intent[0]);

Intent receiver = new Intent(activity, ShareReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 0, receiver, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(first, title, pendingIntent.getIntentSender());
chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extra);
activity.startActivity(chooser);
```

Answer (score 0):

> "but I need to do some communication with the server first"

- Do the communication earlier, store and use it when required?

> "the chooser is simply an interface for selection, , I don't want it
>   to actually start the intent; I will start it manually a little
>   later."

- Have you heard of `ModalBottomSheet`  [reference](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/) to implement the custom chooser for yourself as required.

> "I tried to modify the intents that are collected into the chooser in
>   such a way that they simply redirect back to my own app."

- Use `startActivityForIntent` in that case; when you intent an app, close and return back to your app, handle it `onActivityResult` whatever you want to do.

> " However, I have problem retaining their icons and label."

- Are you referring to the icons and labels of other apps in the chooser dialog?

Comment: 1. That is one option, but I also want to prompt some message after the selection and before entering other apps. I still need to find a way to execute my own code in between.
2. I prefer using the native chooser.
3. I don't want to actually start another app. I want to make the intent look as if it's going to start another app, but it doesn't, and it calls my own activity instead.
4. Yes. I found a method (not shown above) for getting the correct label and icon for most of the apps, but there're some apps (especially built-in ones by Samsung) that I just couldn't get the right result.